# Restarting winbind service on rhel6, service restarts but ansible fails the run

Tags: ansible, rhel6, ansible-playbook, winbind

Seeing this consistently with the playbook below.

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: restart winbind
    service:
      name: winbind
      state: restarted

  - name: reset ssh connection since winbind is dumb and fails the job even though it succeeds
    meta: reset_connection
```

My ansible user logs in, restarts the service and then gets disconnected by winbind causing ansible to think the task failed.

```
Feb 13 17:04:57 server1 sshd[30156]: pam_namespace(sshd:session): user unknown 'ansible-user'
Feb 13 17:04:57 server1 sshd[30156]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ansible-user
Feb 13 17:04:57 server1 sshd[30156]: fatal: login_init_entry: Cannot find user "ansible-user"
Feb 13 17:04:57 server1 sshd[30163]: fatal: mm_request_send: write: Broken pipe
Feb 13 17:04:57 server1 sshd[30163]: fatal: mm_request_send: write: Broken pipe
```

Things I've tried:

1. adding a wait to the restart winbind task. Didn't help, it just disconnected after the set wait time.
2. adding the meta: reset_connection but it disconnects before that's run.

Also, I'm staying logged into the server while this is happening with my normal id so it's just the ansible-user getting disconnected. My id and the ansible-user id are both AD accounts.

I have another playbook for sssd and I'm not seeing this behavior with it. It restarts the service, stays connected and shows the change in the run output.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround for this by ignoring the fatal unreachable error and pausing the playbook run. Not sure this would scale very well so if someone has a better way to do this I'm all ears. Luckily winbind is on it's way out.

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  ignore_unreachable: yes
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: restart winbind
    service:
      name: winbind
      state: restarted

  - name: pause the playbook run to allow winbind to reconnect to AD
    pause:
      seconds: 8

  - name: confirm winbind is running
    service:
      name: winbind
      state: started
```